# Using model's property for requiredif statement without putting it in an actual DOM

Tags: expressiveannotations

I need to validate input field based on a property that is within the same model, however is not being used in the DOM. Something like so:

```
   [RequiredIf("NameRequired", ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public bool NameRequired {get;set} = true;
```

DOM:

```
   @HTML.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name);
```

NameRequired by default is true however it can be changed in other places of the code, which is why it is needed, however when running this code expressiveannotations complains that `NameRequired` field is not found in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the DOM as a hidden field (using @Html.HiddenFor() )